# IIS In use Port Redirection

Tags: iis, redirect, portforwarding

We had a service running in IIS at example.com:88 in one of our server and the url is hardcoded in most of our client apps in android /ios

We needed to move our applications to a new location and this time we had Windows domain among our servers.

That made port 88 busy and occupied with Kerberos.

Now that we have moved all our application and main domain name to the new environment. We are not able to find any workaround to redirect connection coming on port 88 to a different address.

Need help with a workaround to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Multiple Public IPs form your ISP?

if so you can assign/change/add one of those ip to this application/server and have that port also open on that public ip.

Solution depends what kind of router you have and if you are able to acquire additional IPs. Also is it possible to access the app using a FQDN?